# How get element inside of array starting with specify string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to get a specific element starting with specified string the issue is that element is don't coming on same order all the time, I using jquery

example my array is some like this

```
[ 12 : "onedata=some", 13 : "reddata=some red data ", 14 : "nowdata=timenow"]
```

if I want to get the element start with `["nowdata"]` how I can do it sorry I am new in javascript

Comment: `arr.find(str => str.startsWith('nowdata'))`

Comment: The "array" you are showing is not valid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The solution propose here with `.find` is very good, here I write an alternative version which use a simple currying with regular expression.

```js
const arr = ['nowdataabcde', 'xyzabcdenowdata', 'poik']
const findByRegEx = (reg) => (data) => data.find(x => x.match(reg))

const startWithNowDat = findByRegEx('^nowdat')
const r1 = startWithNowDat(arr)
console.log('r1:', r1)

const startWithXyz = findByRegEx('^xyz')
const r2 = startWithXyz(arr)
console.log('r2:', r2)
```